# Pressing PageUp while in textarea moves website out of the window

Tags: html, google-chrome, opera

What happens is that when my cursor is in a `<textarea>` and I've typed a few lines (a.k.a. pressed enter a few times) and I press PageUp, the entire website shifts so that my cursor is in the very left top of the page, while still in the `<textarea>`. The contents of the page are shifted to the left, but no horizontal scrollbar appears, so that the only way to work with the page again is to refresh it.

[image: Image of situation after pressing PageUp]

It seems to be happening due to the many wrappers with margins used plus the `overflow: hidden` that blocks the scrollbar from appearing, but those are necessary for styling the page.

What can I do to stop this from happening, while at the same time not screwing over the entire layout? (about 4000 lines of css... have to make do with what I have)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ARQ35/ (funny side effect: even jsfiddle shifts out of its position when reproducing this issue) *(only in Chrome and Opera)*

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ultrawrap">
    <div class="wrap1">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class="wrap3">
                <section id="content" class="content">
                     <h1>Fiddle of situation</h1>

                     <h3>Press enter a few times and push PageUp.</h3>

                    <form id="form" method="post">
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea cols="85" id="id" name="name" rows="6" style="width: 90%">in here</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler so that there's a scrollbar
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />space filler</div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ultrawrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.wrap1 {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    background: url() repeat-x 50% 0;
}
.wrap2 {
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: -50%;
    background: url() repeat-x 50% 259px;
}
.wrap3:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.wrap3 {
    background: url() repeat-y 50% 0;
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find the cause / solution to this? I'm having it as well.

Comment: Still reproducing in Chrome Win/Linux. Not reproducing in Chrome MacOS

Comment: I opened an issue about this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890248

Answer (score 2):

Here is a VanillaJS workaround (also available on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Soullivaneuh/bcb10c3fae3034474fcd26b66aafc643)):

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.key === 'PageUp' || event.key === 'PageDown') {
    const cursorPosition = event.key === 'PageUp' ? 0 : event.target.textLength;

    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
  }
});
```

It's inspired from this article: http://www.competa.com/blog/chrome-bug-pageup-pagedown-textarea-moves-website-window/

See also the original issue I created: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890248

Answer (score 0):

This bug is reproducing in Chrome on Win/Linux. Not reproducing on MacOS Chrome or any Mozilla, IE. So seems its a Chrome bug.

Seems the only way is to replace page down/up function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").keydown(function(event){
    if (event.which == 33) {
        window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    }
    if (event.which == 34) {
        window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY);
        event.preventDefault();
        textareaLength = $(this).val().length;
        event.target.setSelectionRange(textareaLength,textareaLength);
        $(this).scrollTop(9999);
    }
}); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARQ35/6/